# Sorting/Ranking Tied Scores based on Points Difference

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, rank

I wanted to use Google Sheets to do a competition ranking which can help me to rank or sort the ranking automatically when I key in the Points.
However, there is a condition where there will be a tied happens. If a tie happens, I will take the Score Differences (SD) into consideration. If the Score Differences is low, then it will be rank higher in the tie condition.
See below table for illustration:

[image]

For example: Currently Team A and Team D having the highest PTS, so both of them are currently Rank 1. However, Team D is having a lower SD compare to Team A. So I wanted to have it automatically rank Team D as Rank 1 and Team A as Rank 2.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to create a hidden column with a formula like:

```
=PTS * 10000 - SD
```

(Replacing PTS and SD with the actual cell references)

Multiplying PTS by 10000 ensures it has a higher priority than SD. 
We want to reward low SDs, so we subtract instead of add.

Finally, in the rank column, we can use a formula like:

```
=RANK(HiddenScoreCell, HiddenScoreColumnRange, 0)
```

So, for example, if the HiddenScore column is column K, the actual formula for row 2 might look like

```
=RANK(K2, K:K, 0)
```

The third parameter is 0 as we want higher scores to have a lower rank.

To sort, you can just apply a sort on the Rank column.

Answer (score 0):

With `sort()` you can define multiple sorting criteria (see [documentation][1], e.g.

```
=sort(A2:I5,8,false,7,false)
```

So you're going to sort your table (in A2:I5, change accordingly) based first on PTS, descending, then on SD, descending? You can add more criteria with more pairs of parameters (column index, then descending or ascending as a boolean).

Then you need to compare your team name with with the sorted table and find its rank in the sorted list:

```
=ArrayFormula(match(A2:I5,sort(A2:I5,8,false,7,false),0))
```

Paste that formula in I2 (assuming your table starts in A1 with its headers, otherwise adjust accordingly).

Comment: Updated with the filling of the RANK column, I misread that part in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), RANK(H2:H*9^9-G2:G, H2:H*9^9-G2:G), ))
```

[image: 0]